# Too much white space after rotate image

Tags: css, photo

I have a problem. How to remove white space after rotate image?

[Photo with problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vli8.png)

[image]

Code:

```css
.img-box{
  position:relative;
  width: 100%;
  border: 4px solid #333;
}

.img-box img{
  transform: rotate(44deg);
  width: 70%;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-box">
  <img src="https://publicdomainvectors.org/photos/mystica-LightSaber-Fantasy-2.png" >
</div>
```

Comment: which white space? an image will always be square/rectangle, no matter how you rotate it.

Comment: So how do you delete this unnecessary space?

The sword should have a height of 70px

Answer (score 2):

`transform: rotate` only rotates the image visually, it still takes the same space in the HTML. The easiest way to solve this is to make the image `position: absolute;` and position it as you need it.

```css
.img-box{
  position:relative;
  width: 100%;
  border: 4px solid #333;
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
}

.img-box img{
  transform: rotate(44deg) translateY(-50%);
  width: 70%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-box">
  <img src="https://publicdomainvectors.org/photos/mystica-LightSaber-Fantasy-2.png" >
</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to fill the picture with a picture and give it as a background?

Comment: @Ania you can give the `.img-box` a background imge

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```css
.img-box{
  position:relative;
  width: 100%;
  border: 4px solid #333;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img-box img{
  transform: rotate(44deg);
  width: 70%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -225px;
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-box">
  <img src="https://publicdomainvectors.org/photos/mystica-LightSaber-Fantasy-2.png" >
</div>
```

the hidden overflow will prevent the image from leaking beyond its container.
However the best solution would be to use a graphical editing program such as [photoshop](https://www.adobe.com/products/photoshop.html) or [gimp](https://www.gimp.org/) to edit the photo accordingly

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue. It would be really nice if `image-orientation` wasn't a deprecated CSS property. It'd do exactly what we need. Even though [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/css-image-orientation) says otherwise

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image-orientation

[image: image-orientation not working in Google Chrome]